# jQuery - On Selection option change, show/hide DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Based on the chosen option in a `select` list, I want to show one of the following DIVs:

```
<div id="field-person">Blah</div>

<div id="field-company">Blah 2</div>
```

This is the `select` and jQuery I have right now, which when the `A person` option is selected, *should* show `#field-person`, otherwise it *should* remain hidden:

```
<select name="sub_type" id="sub_type">
  <option value="company">A company</option>
  <option value="person">A person</option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var f = $("#field-person");
  $("#sub_type").change(function() {
    if (this.checked && this.value == "person") {
      f.show();
    } else {
      f.hide();
    }
  }).change()
});
```

Yet when I select the `person` option, nothing happens, same goes for selecting the `company` option. No change, and nothing in the Chrome Console.
Been pulling my hair out on this one for about an hour now, any help would be appreciated, jQuery isn't my strong suit!

Here's a link to the actual code that I'm using: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m87suzo7/#&togetherjs=h3Kza6IFhR)

Comment: I think the only thing you have wrong is the ".change()" call in your js (second to last line).  try changing "}).change()" to "});"

Comment: @Josh That will just trigger the `.change()` event right away.

Comment: yeah, ok... it does need a semi-colon though.  It worked find for me.

Comment: @Josh It doesn't need a semi-colon. Both new lines and semi-colons will separate statements. If statements are separated by new lines, then the semi-colons are optional. Rather, it's just good practice considering other languages.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of your solutions worked... I've edited my question and included a link to a JSFiddle at the bottom with the actual code I'm working with. Tried to run it in JSFiddle, and surprise surprise, it didn't work there either! Any help would be amazing!

Comment: @tristanojbacon You need to include jQuery in the fiddle. [Here is an updated fiddle with it included](https://jsfiddle.net/m87suzo7/1/).

Comment: Ok, so it works in the JSFiddle, but not on my site. I have JQuery and JQuery UI linked in the header, so what else could be going wrong, any ideas?

Comment: @tristanojbacon Does the console say anything, are you sure you are not looking at a cached copy of the old page?

Comment: Nothing in the console, and cleared the cache a few times before I posted on here. Will have another look with fresh eyes tomorrow! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Change your if-statement to:

```
if (this.value == "person") {
   ...
}
```

The `select` element doesn't have a `.checked` property. So `this.checked` returns `undefined`, which will make the condition false.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/n0z8vv07/)